# Noob needs help designing data model & controller

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary

Disclaimer:
I've been learning Objective C/Cocoa for 2 months or so, and I promised myself that I would always try and find the answer myself rather than clogging the internet with dumb noob questions. At this point I'm just confused all over and I think I would benefit at this point from asking questions. I apologize in advance.

Problem:
I'm trying to write a master-detail style app (this is just for practice) called "My Dream Garage". Basically I want to store car objects and their properties. I have a "Car" class that looks like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Car : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *brand, *model, *trimLevel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *modelYear, *engineSizeinL, *weight;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id image;
@end
```

In my main .XIB file I have an NSTableView and a bunch of text labels that will display each property (and an imagewell for the image).

My question is how do I store this data? I understand what NSArray, NSDictionary, ArrayController and DictionaryController are individually. I'm just a little confused on how to make them work together. When I add a new "car", am I supposed to instantiate a new "Car" object with it's properties? At that point do I add the new object to an array and then release the created "Car" object? Do I link the tableview and text-labels to an NSDictionary Controller? I'm not even sure what I should be asking at this point.

Perhaps I'm in a bit over my head. What other than Apple's documentation (which is very good but too verbose for an amateur) would be recommended to learn how to create apps similar to this?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of questions here:

Are you wanting to store them somewhat permanently?  If so, you need to start learning Core Data.

What does the implementation file look like for the Car class?  How are you (or are you) instantiating and initializing a new object?

My class objects usually look something like this:

Interface:

```
@interface UserInfo : NSObject {
    NSString *_networkID;
    NSString *_displayName;
    NSString *_userDomain;
    BOOL _loggedIn;
}
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *networkID;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *displayName;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *userDomain;
@property(nonatomic) BOOL loggedIn;

-(id) initWithUserNetworkID:(NSString *)networkID 
                displayName:(NSString *)displayName  
                 userDomain:(NSString *)userDomain;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "UserInfo.h"

@implementation UserInfo

@synthesize networkID = _networkID;
@synthesize displayName = _displayName;
@synthesize loggedIn = _loggedIn;
@synthesize userDomain = _userDomain;


-(id) initWithUserNetworkID:(NSString *)networkID 
                displayName:(NSString *)displayName 
                 userDomain:(NSString *)userDomain {

    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _networkID = [networkID copy];
        _displayName = [displayName copy];
        _userDomain = [userDomain copy];
        _loggedIn = YES;
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

And I will create a new one with code like this:

```
UserInfo *myUserInfo = [[UserInfo alloc] 
                                initWithUserNetworkID:[loginDictionary objectForKey:@"NetworkID"]  
                                displayName:[loginDictionary objectForKey:@"DisplayName"] 
                                userDomain:[loginDictionary objectForKey:@"UserDomain"]];
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! All I have in the implementation right now is @synthesize with the names of the properties. Ok, so it seems I need to write an initializer inside of Car.m.

I have some questions about your sample code though. You declare the variables in the interface with a _ before them, and then synthesize them. I thought synthesize did the declarations for you (I'm probably totally wrong here). Also what purpose "copy" serve? I haven't seen this before. 

Thank you again!

Comment: Also, in regards to core-data. I haven't really learned terribly much about it yet because I would like to get these simple things down first, but I was figuring on just writing the NSDictionary to a .plist. Is this ill-advised?

Comment: The underscore is naming convention I tend to use for my instance variables.  My properties are then synth'd to the ivar.  This just comes from my early experience with looking at the way Apple does it.  It is actually perfectly fine to use the same name without the underscore if all you are doing is initializing an object.  As far as Core Data, I would not put that off.  Check out Magical Record if you want a nice library to help manage and learn, but CD is an essential tool to have and it is not near the learning curve that most think it is.

Comment: Thank you. I'll start to look into Core Data and probably read up on Magical Record too.